# Php sql request giving 0 result

Tags: php, sql, request

I have a sql request which is supposed to explode char string from :
"toto,tata,titi" to an array ("toto","tata","titi") :

```
$q = $connexion->db->prepare("UPDATE thesaurus_fr SET synonymes_mots = CONCAT(synonymes_mots, ', ', :synonymes_racine) WHERE synonymes_racine = :synonymes_courant");
$syns=explode(",",$_POST['synsList']);
$syns=array_unique($syns);
foreach ($syns as $syn) {
$q->bindValue(":synonymes_racine", $_POST['word']);
$q->bindValue(":synonymes_courant", $syn);
$q->execute();

}
```

At the moment every part of the request seems to work. It doesn't crash but I don't get any result, what am I doing wrong? Thanks for help

Comment: What do you mean by giving 0 result? The update don't work?

Comment: Since your SQL is an `UPDATE` and you run plain execute(), you won't get back any rows.  You can check for successful execution otherwise.

Comment: What kind of result do you expect? The return value of `execute()` is a `boolean` indicating whether or not the query was successful.

Comment: actually the update was not working, and did not update the table (that's what i meant by 0 result) sorry for not being clear enough

Comment: I'm no PHP guy, but generally a 0 means false, anything else (like 1) means true. So your update failed and you get 0 back. Works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check table columns size. The concatenation result may be too long.

Anyway you should get the error after each execute using `print_r($connexion->db->errorInfo());`

http://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php